# Sending WhatsApp messages without confirmation

Tags: android, whatsapp

There are similar questions, yet they do not address the Pebble smartwatch nuance that I mention below.

I am developing an Android app which has an option of sending a text message via WhatsApp. As to my knowledge, there's no possible way to do it except from starting an intent and confirming the message dispatch via WhatsApp itself, as WhatsApp doesn't seem to provide a way of sending a message straight from the other applications, omitting the confirmation step.

Yet, as I have been shown, it is possible to send messages with a pebble smart watch without any intermediate steps.

What is the reason for that and can I somehow bypass the necessity of starting WhatsApp to send a message?